# Better to write large strings versus numerous individual characters with a writer?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a program trying to write to a CSV file, where there could be thousands of comma separated values and thousands of lines.

Right now, I am just calling BufferedWriter's write function repeatedly for each individual character, I am wondering whether performance would improve if I concatenated characters into a long string and wrote them using another class, such as PrintWriter.

Intuitively, I think neither method would be faster because it all boils down to writing individual bytes, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Why are you writing individual characters?

Answer (score 4):

> Intuitively, I think neither method would be faster because it all
>   boils down to writing individual bytes, but I wanted to be sure.

Your assumption is a bit wrong. Less writes with longer data involves (usually) less system calls, and are faster than writing each byte separately.

It's as if you need to move 10 boxes from one city to another, you can take all of the boxes together in one truck or take them one by one. You still have to move 10 boxes X kilometers, but there is a big efficiency difference between the methods.

Note that even when you work with BufferedWriter and call many times to `write`, it doesn't actually write to the file each time (that's why it's called **Buffered** Writer...)

Answer (score 0):

> Right now, I am just calling BufferedWriter's write function repeatedly for each individual character, I am wondering whether performance would improve if I concatenated characters into a long string and wrote them using another class, such as PrintWriter.

It is doubtful that it will make a *significant* difference.

However, my intuition is that the way you are currently doing it is likely to be faster than building a String and writing that.  The alternative, would incur the additional overheads of allocating multiple (at least 2, probably more) heap nodes, and copying the characters into a temporary string.  I don't think that you would recoup that overhead elsewhere.  But this is speculation.  The most important thing is that there is buffering *somewhere* in your output stack.

My advice:

- Don't waste time on this.
- If there is a real (measurable) performance concern, profile your application (or a benchmark) using the two strategies and see which one is better ... for your application.